# How to split file name into variable?

Tags: bash, ksh

Suppose I have a list of csv files with the following format:

```
INT_V1_<Product>_<ID>_<Name>_<ddmmyy>.csv
ASG_B1_V1_<Product>_<ID>_<Name>_<ddmmyy>.csv
```

The **INT_V1_** & **ASG_B1_V1_** is fixed, meaning all the csv files start with it.
How can I split the file names into variable?
For example, I wanted to capture the **Name** & assign it to a variable `$Name`.

Comment: Why the "bash" tag, if you're using ksh on AIX 7.1?

Comment: I wish to produce a bash script. Just that I wanted to try it first on ksh, sorry for causing u trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
file='INT_V1_<Product>_<ID>_<Name>_<ddmmyy>.csv'

setopt extendedglob
if [[ $file = (#b)*_(*)_(*)_(*)_(*).csv ]]; then
  product=$match[1] id=$match[2] name=$match[3] date=$match[4]
fi
```

With `bash` 4.3 or newer, ksh93t or newer or zsh in sh emulation (though in `zsh`, you'd rather simply do `field=("${(@s:_:)field}")` for splitting than using the split+glob non-sense operator of `sh`) you could split the string on `_` characters and reference them from the end:

```
IFS=_
set -o noglob
field=($file) # split+glob  operator
date=${field[-1]%.*}
name=${field[-2]}
id=${field[-3]}
product=${field[-4]}
```

Or (bash 3.2 or newer):

```
if [[ $file =~ .*_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.csv$ ]]; then
  product=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  id=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  name=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  date=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
fi
```

(that assumes `$file` contains valid text in the current locale which  is not guaranteed for file names unless you fix the locale to C or other locale with a single-byte per character charset).

Like `zsh`'s `*` above, the `.*` is *greedy*. So the first one will eat as many `*_` as possible, so the remaining `.*` will only match `_`-free strings.

With `ksh93`, you could do

```
pattern='*_(*)_(*)_(*)_(*).csv'
product=${file//$pattern/\1}
id=${file//$pattern/\2}
name=${file//$pattern/\3}
date=${file//$pattern/\4}
```

In a POSIX `sh` script, you could use the `${var#pattern}`, `${var%pattern}` standard parameter expansion operators:

```
rest=${file%.*} # remove .csv suffix
date=${rest##*_} # remove everything on the left up to the rightmost _
rest=${rest%_*} # remove one _* from the right
name=${rest##*_}
rest=${rest%_*}
id=${rest##*_}
rest=${rest%_*}
product=${rest##*_}
```

Or use the split+glob operator again:

```
IFS=_
set -o noglob
set -- $file
shift "$(($# - 4))"
product=$1 id=$2 name=$3 date=${4%.*}
```

Comment: I'm using bash on AIX7.1 & I'm currently testing in ksh. Somehow I encounter an error stating `ksh: file: 0403-046 The specified subscript cannot be greater than 4095.` for `${field[-1]}` or anything in the form `${x[n]}`.

Comment: @Juliet, `${field[-1]}` was for `bash-4.3+`. For `ksh`, use any of the "POSIX" solutions. Support for negative subscript was not added before ksh93t (a feature originating in zsh).

Comment: Ok, noted. Thanks alot, the scripts are working fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can take the values of your field `<Name>` with this command:

```
cut -d'<' -f4 < csvlist | sed -e 's/>_//g'
```

(or with `awk`):

```
awk -F'<' '{print $4}' < csvlist | sed -e 's/>_//g'
```

And you can put them in a variable like this:

```
variable_name=$(cut -d'<' -f4 < csvlist | sed -e 's/>_//g')
```

or

```
awk -F'<' '{print $4}' < csvlist | sed -e 's/>_//g'
```

It is not clear in the question if you want the same variable for all the values or one single variable for each one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
file='INT_V1_<Product>_<ID>_<Name>_<ddmmyy>.csv'
IFS=\_ read -r x x product id name date x <<< "$file"
date=${date%.*}
```

Comment: Note that `_` is not special and doesn't need to be quoted. That assumes the file name doesn't contain newline characters. You may want to add a `-d ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$ basename file.csv .csv 
file
```